# Why is HTML button containing image so wide?

Tags: html, image, button

Our 8 year old son wrote the below HTML code:

```html
<button>
        <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEMUv.png' height=7% width=7% >
</button>
```

He is upset because the button is so wide:

[image: screenshot of results]

He wants me to explain why the button is so wide, but I can't. Can anyone help me with explaining that?

Comment: You can't use units with `height` and `width` attributes : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: @JonP Good point. But replacing `height=7% width=7%` with `style='height:7%;width:7%'` produces the same behaviour with regard to button width, so that's not the cause of the issue he is complaining about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set width of the image as percentage, `button` holds original width of the image and just the image shrinks by `7%`.

You can avoid it by setting absolute width for the image.

```html
<button>
  <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEMUv.png' width="25">
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

[The percentage measurement is often considered as a percentage of the **parent** element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage)

This is where things get a little circular. The width of the button element is set by the dimensions of the image. The image element is then styled as a percentage of the button **not** the actual image itself.

Use absolute units (px) instead of %

```css
button img {
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
}
```

```html
<button>
        <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEMUv.png' >
</button>
```